# How to integrate JIRA with salesforce using OAuth 2.0

Tags: integration, oauth2, connected-apps, auth-provider

I am banging my head against the wall from the last couple of weeks to just set up the authentication between JIRA cloud and salesforce, I didn't get any proper documentation to create a connected application in Jira to generate client Id and secret so that I can set up an auth provider in salesforce to use it with the named credentials, if I am not following the right path, please feel free to correct me.
      In one of my unsuccessful attempts, I tried to generate OAuth credentials (currently in beta in Jira) and used the same in AUTH provider in salesforce but still, when I save named credentials I get identity provider error and also I am not sure on what exactly I need to pass for **Authorization Endpoint URL** and **Token End Point URL**
      I would highly appreciate if someone would help me to generate client id secret from JIRA other then generating the same by clicking on **generate OAuth credentials** button on Jira as this has limited access and also I would be very grateful if someone also helps me with **Authorization Endpoint URL** and **Token End Point URL**

here is my **Auth provider**

[image: Auth provider]

**Named Credentials:**

[image]

And when I save the named credentials I get below error

[image]

I have generated client id secret by clicking on **OAuth credentials beta** and this doesn't seem the right way to generate client id and secret as it is in beta and provides only limited access.

JIRA Documentation is not at all helpful.

[image]

If I generate my client id and secret from the below link

https://developer.atlassian.com/apps/

then I get a different error as shown below.

[image]

Comment: This link holds some information https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/38541/how-to-integrate-jira-with-salesforce/38542#38542

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but this link doesn't explain Auth and I am struggling with OAuth authentication.

Comment: The Jira documentation will explain the way to authenticate using oAuth - https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/oauth/

Comment: this link is for the JIRA server and I am on the JIRA cloud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to authenticate my OAuth 2.0 with the following configuration. [image]

[image]

For the Auth. provider  my Endpoint URL was:

```
https://auth.atlassian.com/authorize?audience=api.atlassian.com
```

My token endpoint was

```
https://auth.atlassian.com/oauth/token
```

My default scopes were:

```
read:jira-work manage:jira-project manage:jira-configuration read:jira-user write:jira-work manage:jira-data-provide offline_access
```

Also I made sure that the callback url in my Jira app was the same callback url in the Auth. provider (https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-authorization-code-grants-3lo-for-apps/?_ga=2.21088251.1341824495.1591632254-1686398826.1589413008 for more info on Jira App)

I used the Auth. Provider in my Named credential and made sure to keep Scope empty so it would use the default scope in the Auth Provider.

Turning off "Generate Authorization Header" helped for my API calls to not return 401 during my tests.

Unfortunately I still don't see the issues on my Jira when I do API calls but I hope this helps you get closer to solving your problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help, finally authenticated successfully, and just to clarify your last line, are you able to make API call or getting an issue.

Comment: I have created another thread for issue in callout, if you are not getting any issue then please suggest, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308964/status-code-401-client-must-be-authenticated-to-access-this-resource

Comment: When i do the GET api callout to "callout:JiraOauth/rest/api/3/search" i get the response "{"startAt":0, "maxResults":50, "total":0 "issues":[]}" when i actually except the api call to return the issues on my Jira

Comment: I don't know why but I am getting 401 for this.*callout:JiraOauth/rest/api/3/search*

Client must be authenticated to access this resource, but my named credentials status is authenticated.

Comment: This probably isn't helpful but I get "{"startAt":0, "maxResults":50, "total":0 "issues":[]}"  when i disable "Generate Authorization Header" in Named Crendtials, otherwise I get the same error as you

Answer (score 0):

All authentication details for Jira are mentioned in their documentation. Hope the below will help to put you in the right path. 
You will also need to create an **Auth Provider** and link it to your named credential.

**Jira Cloud :**
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/basic-auth-for-rest-apis/

**oAuth :**
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-authorization-code-grants-3lo-for-apps/#authcode

**The Authorization Endpoint URL :**

```
https://auth.atlassian.com/authorize
```

**Token End Point URL**

```
https://auth.atlassian.com/oauth/token
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I am trying to follow these documentation and I still stuck with the same issue, I have updated my question with screenshot.

Answer (score -1):

1. Remove default scope from Salesforce Auth Provider . Alternatively
   you can set it to the scope defined in JIRA. Right now I can see it
   set to ADMIN. Verify and replace.
2. Provide the correct callback URL in JIRA Oauth screen. This should
   be the Salesforce URL that get redirected to on correct
   authentication/authorization.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I removed default scope from Auth provider but still not able to authenticate and as per my knowledge I am providing correct Authorization end point URL rest I am not sure, please suggest

Comment: Along with Default Scope, clear off the URL Suffix, Token Issuer

Comment: **URL Suffix** and **Token Endpoint URL** both are required fields.

Comment: You can leave URL Suffix, other field which I mentioned earlier was Token Issuer and not Token Endpoint URL. Keep scope blank

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding, I have updated Auth provider as you explained removed default scope and token issuer and add the updated auth provider screenshot on my question, but still the issue is same.