# Status code 401 Client must be authenticated to access this resource

Tags: apex, integration, oauth2

I have created Auth provider in Salesforce, linked it with Named credentials and it Authenticated successfull, now I am doing callout using below apex.

apex class:

```
private static string dashboardEndpoint = 'callout:IntegrateJira/rest/api/3/dashboard';
private static string issueEndpoint ='callout:IntegrateJira/rest/api/3/issue/IN-1/properties/issue.support';
private static string userEndpoint ='callout:IntegrateJira/rest/api/3/user';     

public static void jiraCallout() {

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(userEndpoint);
    req.setMethod('GET');       
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
    System.debug(res.getBody());
}
```

I get status code 200 if I am using dashboardEndpoint but if I use any other end point, I am keep getting below error

> Status code 401 Client must be authenticated to access this resource

and on Named Credentials I can see status is **Authenticated** what other type of authentication is it expecting, can someone please suggest?

Comment: does the user (on behalf of you are hitting the endpoints) have access to the dashboard?

Comment: no, I am the only user. there is no other user created so far

Comment: Could you please make sure you have access to the dashboards, this might be the issue, or may be try to hit the url with another client like postman?

Comment: I am the system administrator in JIRA and I can access only dashboards not any other thing.

Answer (score 2):

This guide helped me to successfully do APIs call with OAuth 2.0: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/oauth-2-authorization-code-grants-3lo-for-apps/

You can follow the guide to find your cloudId and then I think the only changes you need to make are :

1. Change the URL for your Named Credential to `https://api.atlassian.com`
2. Change the request endpoint to:`'callout:IntegrateJira/ex/jira/' + CLOUDID + API;` .

   For example: `https://api.atlassian.com/ex/jira/11223344-a1b2-3b33-c444-def123456789/rest/api/2/project`

I didn't have luck with `rest/api/3/user` because it required `'accountId' parameter` but all my other API calls worked successfully. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, would you please point me to the direction where I can get endpoints to fetch bugs and sprints as well

Comment: You can find jira API documentations here: https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/